# What is the meaning of "of" in the following sentence?

Tags: prepositions

What is the meaning of "of" in the following sentence, "We can speak of our concerns" ?

Why in this sentence do we use the preposition of? Should we not express the sentence in verb + object form without the preposition of.

What is the exact difference in the meaning between "We can speak of our concerns" and "We can speak our concerns" ?

Comment: Do you tell me that This sentenece, "We can speak our concerns" is wrong ? if so, why ?

Comment: @user22046 the same reason that _I'm listening you_ is wrong. _I'm listening **to** you_. Collocation is at play here. We use certain verbs with certain prepositions in certain contexts.

Comment: @user22046 It's wrong because *speak* is used intranstively.

Comment: hmm..  She sings a song(right)..., ....We speak our concerns(wrong)...Why do these differences arise?  Do we have to memorize this difference without easily identifying it?

Comment: @user22046 Rule of thumb: Most action verbs are transitive. But this rule wouldn't cover everything, keep a dictionary as your best friend.

Answer (score 1):

When you use *speak* in the sense of *talk to someone about something* it's **always** followed by an **adverb** or a **preposition**. For example,

> I spoke to her last Wednesday.
>
> They did not want to speak with reporters.
>
> It was the first time she had ever spoken of marriage.
>
> I know her by sight, but not to speak to.

About your question about meaning, I can roughly say *of* means *about*.

Source: [LDOCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/speak)

Comment: @Lucian Sava I suppose this is a literary way to say _give someone advice_ **as if** this is a particular type of language as in _I don’t speak a word of French_. Anyway, you might want to send your comment to LDOCE as an objection. _May you get a propor answer_. :)

Comment: I don't know why.        Subject + Verb + what? or who? = Direct Object. We can speak  our concerns ==> subject:We. verb:speak. direct object:our concerns.   Why in this sentence do we use the preposition of?

Comment: @user22046 I think the only way I can answer your question is to appeal to the concept of **collocations** which is _the natural way that words go together and native speakers tend to use it that way_ e.g. you don't say _he explained me this_ you say _he explained this **to** me_ although the general rule for _direct object_ and _indirect object_ tells us this is possible as in _he sent me flowers_; people simply don't use _explain_ in that way. I'm sure if you look into your own language you find plenty of these.